# Stopping my tooltips from flickering

Tags: javascript, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Having a problem getting my javascript working properly . For a single tooltip, it works great. But when I rollover multiple tips, I get a flickering effect. It seems the mouseover, out events are being 'queued' or something.

I've created a fiddle where you can see what I'm talking about
http://jsfiddle.net/eco_bach/dpFBQ/2/

Any other optimization suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `.stop(true, true)` before the `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` methods to end any current animation. This will stop it flickering as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpFBQ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating and animating the tool tip every time you mouse over an element, so the flickering is expecting. I suspect you want to open it once and then just update its location and content when hovering others.

In that case you will need to track wether the tooltip is already open or not, if it is update its content and location but skip animating it. If not, do do the animation.